# Joomla and XMLRPC

Tags: python, joomla, xml-rpc

How do I get started with getting going with XML-RPC with joomla? I've been looking around for documentation and finding nothing...

I'd like to connect to a joomla server, (after enabling the Core Joomla XML-RPC plugin), and be able to do things like login and add an article, and tweak all the parameters of the article if possible.

My xml-rpc client implementation will be in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the book "Mastering Joomla 1.5 Extension and Framework Development" has a nice explanation of that.

Joomla has a fex XML-RPC plugins that let you do a few things, like the blogger API interface. (plugins/xmlrpc/blogger.php)

You should create your own XML-RPC plugin to do the custom things you want.