# Joomla XML-RPC & .NET

Tags: .net, joomla, xml-rpc, joomla1.5

I Want to build a .NET application that can Communicate with Joomla so that i can Access the Joomla Database and components to Perform Various Functions.

So how do i get started in order to do so. I need to access the Joomla Articles and Jcal Event Calender and display the Data on .NET WinForm and Windows Mobile Application later on.

So i am looking For:
How to work with Joomla XM-RPC

&

Using it in .NET Application !

Answer (score 1):

You need to do couple of things:

1. Create XML-RPC plug-in for you application
2. Create .NET application that will interact with your XML-RPC

To gets started you need to know how XML-RPC works, see [their site for  documentation](http://www.xmlrpc.com/). Look at Joomla's XML-RPC plug-in and modify it to your needs. Create .NET application to interact with the site via remote procedure call, which is very simle (just requesting url with parameters and keys). Your .NET will receive XML back, parse it (by using LINQ or DOMParser, or SAX if you like *jk) and implement your program logic.

See following threads:

- [Joomla and XMLRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694205/joomla-and-xmlrpc)
- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=262894
- [Joomla and XMLRPC: 'Incorrect parameters passed to method...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362252/joomla-and-xmlrpc-incorrect-parameters-passed-to-method)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this great library: [XML-RPC.NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/). It should make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

we've updated xml-rpc for Joomla for future versions btw., adding also methods for major plugins. you can download it here http://xapp-studio.com/downloads